# Rails Installer - How to update just ruby from 1.9.x to 2.0 +?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

I installed with railsinstaller with Ruby version 1.9.3

Can I simply change my Gemfile to specify a different version of Ruby, or does updating Ruby not work like gems? I don't want to break anything during my fiddling.

I wish to avoid:

1) having to reinstall railsinstaller alpha with 2.0.0

2) downloading a separate package like RVM

3) having to do backup operations with files, databases, etc.

Gem updates can bypass all 3 obstacles very easily. Is this also possible with Ruby itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended you use RVM.
Then you can switch between Ruby versions.
You will still have to tell the Gemfile to use ruby '2.0.0'

Comment: so RVM does not cause compatibility issues with railsinstaller.

Comment: I dont think so, railsinstaller is just a package of gems, I think you can upgrade without a problem. It looks like railsinstaller comes with RVM, so you dont have to set that up.

Comment: the windows version doesn't list RVM as included

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the mac one, but installing RVM, and upgrading so be fine.